# Running Python file within its self

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to run another Python File from a Main Python File. 
For example:

I have a file Main.py and its servers as the main directory for the following files:

- Surface Area Calculator
- Scientific Calculator

How would you import a Python file to them. I was hoping to do this so I can keep myself organized.

Could that possible open a file with a .txt format but written in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to point a Python file to them, you just need the [`import`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) keyword to do that.

So, from your **Main.py** file you can do:

```
from other_python_file import SurfaceAreaCalculator, ScientificCalculator
```

This way you will "run" **other_python_file.py** file within **Main.py**.

If you want to run content from a **TXT** file, I guess you could use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) or [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) to do that. Don't know if it is such a good idea though...

Comment: Yes, but there's no reason to do that when you can just use `file.py` and import it.